# Rails, access an array inside of GooglePlaces::Spot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

I am trying to access the photo_reference inside of a GooglePlaces::Spot. It looks the following way

```
@address_components=nil,
 @formatted_address="78 Commercial St, Edinburgh EH6 6LX, United Kingdom",
 @id="c1b1a2a52d3d945b085f6bda7ab4a439a592428c",
 @lat=55.97703809999999,
 @lng=-3.172689199999999,
 @name="The Kitchin",
 @photos=
  [#<GooglePlaces::Photo:0x00560bdba7aa70
    @api_key="AIzaSyADZdRRUvCvt0ARmLVrlFlXaB8f4l1ItJE",
    @height=371,
    @html_attributions=["<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/101066273666274573257/photos\">The Kitchin</a>"],
    @photo_reference=
     "CoQBcwAAAE0yucuHEWBiQfVjtGT7CgDAK--L6XU9LHxiqip8mhzc0yzErxGAN17AsucENKAHWpo6dx8ruj5c7SnXd6B0qlJCClaVOF1yNRVWKKxUOD5ZcCY-IifpNGSDvmew4ZaWAa3-GA0XjxcKkoA6CThq-aVjCltbmE4t75l9daQZeUxkEhApm-vcdmqKMXIx3UcFNZkHGhRWqyXIQkIVs9unWyBGHZtGpTqS8A",
    @width=371>],
 @place_id="ChIJLy3eIwS4h0gRe4oubEitnNQ",
 @postal_code=nil
```

I access the @photos by writing u.photos but I do not know how to return the @photo_reference inside of u.photos. ANy ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use [`photo_reference`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/google_places/0.30.0/GooglePlaces%2FPhoto%3Aphoto_reference):

```
u.photos.first.photo_reference
```

To get a list of all photo_references from the `u.photo` array you'd go with:

```
u.photos.inject([]) { |arr, photo| arr << photo.photo_reference }
```

See [docs](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/google_places/0.30.0/GooglePlaces/Photo) for more info on available methods.

Comment: I get an error "NoMethodError: undefined method `photo_reference' for #<Array:0x00560bdba7aa98>"

Comment: @KristiyanTsvetanov use `u.photo.first.photo_reference`

Comment: Yep... that worked. I will mark your answer as Accepted.

Comment: @KristiyanTsvetanov glad to help. Advice: always go to docs first ;)